# Linux/Unix command to join N lines of input with delimiters?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

At the Linux/Unix command line, I want to turn this:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
.
.
.
```

into this:

```
A,B,C
A,B,C
...
```

Is there a simple built-in command to do this, or does this require diving into Awk, Perl, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know such built-in. Using `Bash` you can:

```
while read a && read b && read c ; do echo $a,$b,$c ; done < file
```

Comment: If you have only 5 lines, you may not want to lose lines 4 and 5 just because you don't have line 6.

Comment: I suggest: `while read one && { read two ; read three; true; }`

Answer (score 5):

That is horrible, surely something like

```
tr \\n ' '
```

would do the same thing?

So for e.g. to join lines of the file *file_lines* use

```
cat file_lines | tr \\n ' '
```

Comment: He didn't want all of it on a single line, it seems.

Comment: Exactly. Referencing the problem statement, this would produce a single line with everything on it (A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C ...) which is not what was requested.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX solution with `pr`:

```
pr -3 -a -t -s, file
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html

Comment: Clever, but could fail with a `pr: page width too narrow` error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky enough to have no spaces in the input, then

```
xargs -n3 echo |tr ' ' ,
```

would do it.

Comment: That's a good one that I was going to suggest. Very elegant. If you do have spaces, use `xargs -l3`

Comment: The `tr` will mangle the output if there are spaces in the input, even with `xargs -l`

Comment: Alright then, I'll provide my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $1, NR%3 ? "," : "\n"}'
```

It is a lot faster for huge files than the proposed `xargs` solution.

Update:
If number of lines is not a multiple of 3.

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", d, $1; d=NR%3 ? "," : "\n"}'
```

Comment: Will display extra commas if there lines read are not a multiple of 3. I suggest: `awk '{turn=NR%3 ; printf "%s%s%s", (turn == 1) ? "" : ",", $1, turn ? "" : "\n"}'`

Answer (score 1):

GNU/Linux command to merge every group of N lines into one line is a **`paste`** command. 
This is not a built-in command, but it is part of the coreutils, so it is installed by default.

Your example will look as follows:

```
user@host:~$ cat ABC.text
A
B
C
A
B
C

user@host:~$ cat ABC.text | paste - - - -d,
A,B,C
A,B,C
```

If there is just **5** input lines, then last output line will be incomplete:

```
user@host:~$ cat ABC.text | head -5 | paste - - - -d,
A,B,C
A,B,
```

If we want to group lines not by 3, but by 2:

```
user@host:~$ cat ABC.text | paste - - -d,
A,B
C,A
B,C
```

If there is just **5** input lines, then last output line will be incomplete:

```
user@host:~$ cat ABC.text | head -5 | paste - - -d,
A,B
C,A
B,
```

As you can see, you are putting as many `-` (which in this case refers to `stdin`), as number of lines you want to merge into one. If the number of input lines is insufficient, the last joint line will be incomplete.

To handle a larger number of lines in a group, you just have to add more `-`.

See `man paste` for additional information.

---

Let's look at a real example: output of `iwlist` command. First, let's  choose only *ESSID* lines from the output (and let's add a bit of obfuscation; this part will not change, so it can be ignored):

```
user@host:~$ iwlist wifi scanning | grep "ESSID" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/\(ess: ...\)\(.*\)\(...$\)/\1XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' -e "s/\(ESSID:\"\)\(.....\)\(.*\"\)/\1\2......\"/g" 
ESSID:"DIREC......"
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
ESSID:"the g......"
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
ESSID:"sunny......"
ESSID:"beeli......"
ESSID:"Beeli......"
ESSID:"HG530......"
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
ESSID:"Home_......"
```

If later we want to add *addresses* to our output, then the output will turn into alternating lines with *addresses* and *ESSID*.

```
user@host:~$ iwlist wifi scanning | grep "Cell\|ESSID" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/\(ess: ...\)\(.*\)\(...$\)/\1XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' -e "s/\(ESSID:\"\)\(.....\)\(.*\"\)/\1\2......\"/g"
Cell 01 - Address: 12:XX:XX:XX:XX:7A
ESSID:"DIREC......"
Cell 02 - Address: 70:XX:XX:XX:XX:32
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 03 - Address: E0:XX:XX:XX:XX:73
ESSID:"the g......"
Cell 04 - Address: 44:XX:XX:XX:XX:D2
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 05 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:54
ESSID:"sunny......"
Cell 06 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:7C
ESSID:"beeli......"
Cell 07 - Address: EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:DC
ESSID:"Beeli......"
Cell 08 - Address: C8:XX:XX:XX:XX:9F
ESSID:"HG530......"
Cell 09 - Address: CC:XX:XX:XX:XX:02
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 10 - Address: 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:E8
ESSID:"Home_......"
```

To merge every two lines into one, add `| paste - -`:

```
user@host:~$ iwlist wifi scanning | grep "Cell\|ESSID" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/\(ess: ...\)\(.*\)\(...$\)/\1XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' -e "s/\(ESSID:\"\)\(.....\)\(.*\"\)/\1\2......\"/g" | paste - -
Cell 01 - Address: 12:XX:XX:XX:XX:7A    ESSID:"DIREC......"
Cell 02 - Address: 70:XX:XX:XX:XX:32    ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 03 - Address: E0:XX:XX:XX:XX:73    ESSID:"the g......"
Cell 04 - Address: 44:XX:XX:XX:XX:D2    ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 05 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:54    ESSID:"sunny......"
Cell 06 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:7C    ESSID:"beeli......"
Cell 07 - Address: EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:DC    ESSID:"Beeli......"
Cell 08 - Address: C8:XX:XX:XX:XX:9F    ESSID:"HG530......"
Cell 09 - Address: CC:XX:XX:XX:XX:02    ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Cell 10 - Address: 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:E8    ESSID:"Home_......"
```

If later we want to add a *Protocol*, *Bit rates* and *Frequency*, then the output will be a list of groups of 5 lines eash (*address*, *ESSID*, *Protocol*, *Frequency*, and *Bit Rates*).

```
user@host:~$ iwlist wifi scanning | grep "Cell\|ESSID\|Protocol\|Rates\|Frequency" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/\(ess: ...\)\(.*\)\(...$\)/\1XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' -e "s/\(ESSID:\"\)\(.....\)\(.*\"\)/\1\2......\"/g"
Cell 01 - Address: 12:XX:XX:XX:XX:7A
ESSID:"DIREC......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11gn
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
Cell 02 - Address: 70:XX:XX:XX:XX:32
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 03 - Address: E0:XX:XX:XX:XX:73
ESSID:"the g......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
Cell 04 - Address: 44:XX:XX:XX:XX:D2
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 05 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:54
ESSID:"sunny......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
Cell 06 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:7C
ESSID:"beeli......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
Cell 07 - Address: EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:DC
ESSID:"Beeli......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
Cell 08 - Address: C8:XX:XX:XX:XX:9F
ESSID:"HG530......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
Cell 09 - Address: CC:XX:XX:XX:XX:02
ESSID:"MGTS_......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 10 - Address: 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:E8
ESSID:"Home_......"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)
Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
```

To merge every 5 lines into one, just add `| paste - - - - -`.

```
user@host:~$ iwlist wifi scanning | grep "Cell\|ESSID\|Protocol\|Rates\|Frequency" | sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/\(ess: ...\)\(.*\)\(...$\)/\1XX:XX:XX:XX\3/g' -e "s/\(ESSID:\"\)\(.....\)\(.*\"\)/\1\2......\"/g" | paste - - - - - 
Cell 01 - Address: 12:XX:XX:XX:XX:7A    ESSID:"DIREC......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11gn  Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1) Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
Cell 02 - Address: 70:XX:XX:XX:XX:32    ESSID:"MGTS_......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1) Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 03 - Address: E0:XX:XX:XX:XX:73    ESSID:"the g......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg  Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1) Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
Cell 04 - Address: 44:XX:XX:XX:XX:D2    ESSID:"MGTS_......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1) Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 05 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:54    ESSID:"sunny......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg  Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4) Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
Cell 06 - Address: 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:7C    ESSID:"beeli......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3) Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
Cell 07 - Address: EC:XX:XX:XX:XX:DC    ESSID:"Beeli......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6) Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
Cell 08 - Address: C8:XX:XX:XX:XX:9F    ESSID:"HG530......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8) Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
Cell 09 - Address: CC:XX:XX:XX:XX:02    ESSID:"MGTS_......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7) Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
Cell 10 - Address: 28:XX:XX:XX:XX:E8    ESSID:"Home_......" Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)    Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
```

EOT

Answer (score 1):

For my memo.

```
$ cat split.sh
#!/bin/bash -x
pr -3tas, <input # Zombo's
paste -d, - - - <input # DIG mbl's
awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":"\n"' <input
perl -pe'$.%3&&s/\n/,/' <input
split -l3 --filter=paste\ -sd, <input
perl -l0pe '$_.=$.%3?",":"\n"' <input

$ ./split.sh
+ pr -3tas,
A,B,C
A,B,C
+ paste -d, - - -
A,B,C
A,B,C
+ awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":"\n"'
A,B,C
A,B,C
+ perl '-pe$.%3&&s/\n/,/'
A,B,C
A,B,C
+ split -l3 '--filter=paste -sd,'
A,B,C
A,B,C
+ perl -l0pe '$_.=$.%3?",":"\n"'
A,B,C
A,B,C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def njoin(filename, outfn="", n=3, linesuffix=" "):
    if not outfn:
        outfn = filename + ".join"
    with open(filename) as infh, open(outfn, "w") as outfh:
        nline = 0
        for line in infh:
            if nline % n != n-1:
                line = line.rstrip() + linesuffix
            outfh.write(line)
            nline += 1
```

In your case you can use the function like this:

```
njoin("/path/to/file", n=3, linesuffixe=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample you gave have 3 lines but your topic emphasize on **N** lines of input, so I would assume that 3 lines is only for illustration purpose, and what you really need is that **N** lines of input, which could be as much as over 10, which in turn making that accepted bash script unmanageable.

There are simple built-in commands to do this, without diving into Awk, or Perl. Here is one way.

First, the sample input,

```
 $ seq 12 | cat -n 
     1  1
     2  2
     3  3
     4  4
     5  5
     6  6
     7  7
     8  8
     9  9
    10  10
    11  11
    12  12
```

Now suppose `N=4`:

```
N=4
$ seq 12 | cat -n | sed 's/$/,/' | xargs -l$N | sed 's/,$//'
1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4
5 5, 6 6, 7 7, 8 8
9 9, 10 10, 11 11, 12 12
```

I believe that should be close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on [Timo's](https://superuser.com/a/1484159/545165):

```
join_inputs_by_n () {
    awk -v STEP=${1:-4} \
        '{turn=NR%STEP;printf "%s%s%s", (turn == 1) ? "" : ",", $1, turn ? "" : "\n"}
         END { printf turn ? "\n":"" }'
}
```

Where `STEP` is the amount of lines we want to join. It covers non-multiple sequences, and add a final end of line if so:

```
$ seq 1 8 | join_inputs_by_n 4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

$ seq 1 8 | join_inputs_by_n 3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8
```